# Unlistening to events using unlistenByKey in google closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure

[goog.events](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_events_events.js.html) provides an unlistenByKey method allowing the specific deregistration of a listener by its unique identity. Is it correct that the only way to obtain this key is by calling either `goog.events.listen` again with each event type listened for or by calling `goog.events.getListener` with each event type listened for?

e.g.

```
var eventKeys = new Array(2);
goog.events.listen(document, ['mousedown', 'touchstart'], this.pressStartHandler_, false, this);
eventKey[0] = goog.events.getListener(document, 'mousedown', this.pressStartHandler_, false, this);
eventKey[1] = goog.events.getListener(document, 'touchstart', this.pressStartHandler_, false, this);
```

**EDIT**

Barring better advice from an answerer, I'm wrote the following wrapper to get the keys:

```
/**
 * Wrap goog.events.listen to capture all of the event keys of the requested listeners.
 * 
 * @param {(EventTarget |
 *          goog.events.EventTarget | null)} src The node to listen to events on.
 * @param {(Array |
 *          null | string)} type Event type or array of event types.
 * @param {(Object |
 *          null)} listener Callback method, or an object with a handleEvent function.
 * @param {(boolean |
 *          undefined)} opt_capt Whether to fire in capture phase (defaults to false).
 * @param {(Object |
 *          null | undefined)} opt_handler Element in whose scope to call the listener.
 * @returns {Array.<number>} Array of keys for listeners
 */
wias.util.listen = function(src, type, listener, opt_capt, opt_handler)
{
  var i;
  var keys = new Array();
  goog.events.listen(src, type, listener, opt_capt, opt_handler);
  if (type instanceof Array)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < type.length; i++)
    {
      keys.push(goog.events.getListener(src, type[i], listener, opt_capt, opt_handler).key);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    keys.push(goog.events.getListener(src, type, listener, opt_capt, opt_handler).key);
  }
  return keys;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find `goog.events.EventHandler` useful.

```
// Note that all handler callbacks receive 'this' as the opt_handler, by default.
var handler = new goog.events.EventHandler(this);
handler.listen(
    document, ['mousedown', 'touchstart'], this.pressStartHandler_, false);

// Some time later...
handler.removeAll();
```

To answer the original question, `goog.events.listen` also returns the key when used with a single event type. You could be slightly more correct and concise in your above implementation by iterating over each event type, calling `goog.events.listen` for each, and storing the key for each.

```
wias.util.listen = function(src, type, listener, opt_capt, opt_handler) {
  var keys = new Array();
  if (type instanceof Array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
      keys.push(goog.events.listen(src, type, listener, opt_capt, opt_handler));
    }
  } else {
    keys.push(goog.events.listen(src, type, listener, opt_capt, opt_handler));
  }
  return keys;
};
```